# How to disable popup on Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, popup

I have once opened a website on Chrome for Android. By mistake, I allowed the popup.

Now I am not able to find how to disable this popup. As a result, every time I open the URL (which is quite often), the pop-up is opened which is a pain.

How to disable the popup for a website for which it was enabled earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Chrome for Android, go to `Settings > Content settings > Website settings`. Select the website in concern, and clear the data / cache for it.